# JQuery add setInterval() in scroll script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having difficulties with adding setInterval() function in this scroll news script:

```
jQuery.fn.liScroll = function(settings) {
  settings = jQuery.extend({
    travelocity: 0.03
  }, settings);

  return this.each(function() {
    var $strip = jQuery(this);
    $strip.addClass("newsticker")
    var stripHeight = 1;
    $strip.find("li").each(function(i) {
      stripHeight += jQuery(this, i).outerHeight(true);
    });
    var $mask = $strip.wrap("<div class='mask'></div>");
    var $tickercontainer = $strip.parent().wrap("<div class='tickercontainer'></div>");
    var containerHeight = $strip.parent().parent().height();
    $strip.height(stripHeight);
    var totalTravel = stripHeight;
    var defTiming = totalTravel / settings.travelocity;

    function scrollnews(pace, temp) {
      $strip.animate({
        top: '-=' + pace
      }, temp, "linear", function() {
        $strip.css("top", containerHeight);
        scrollnews(totalTravel, defTiming);
      });
    }
    scrollnews(totalTravel, defTiming);
    $strip.hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).stop();
      },
      function() {
        var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
        var residualSpace = offset.top + stripHeight;
        var residualTime = residualSpace / settings.travelocity;
        scrollnews(residualSpace, residualTime);
      });
  });
};
```

I've added this code between last two brackets:

```
setInterval("jQuery.fn.liScroll.travelocity()", 1000);
```

And at the end of the script:

```
$(function(){
  $("ul#ticker01").liScroll();
});
```

The script is working, but when it reaches last -li-, it wont repeat the whole thing again. Any hints?

Comment: Please share codepen link with working code.

Comment: Here it is: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPvOgr

Answer (score 1):

Unfotunately, nothing happens in the pen that you provided.

But, `jQuery.fn.liScroll.travelocity` is not defined anywhere.So, you cannot invoke that in interval.

May be what you are trying to do is:

```
$(function () {
    setInterval(function () { 
        $("ul#ticker01").liScroll(); 
    }, 1000);
});
```